# Check if JSON response contains a string using Powershell script

Tags: json, powershell

```cs
$w = $wallets | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
```

```json
{
    "result":  {
                   "wallets":  [
                                   {
                                       "name":  "W1"
                                   },
                                   {
                                       "name":  "W2"
                                   },
                                   {
                                       "name":  "W3"
                                   },
                                   {
                                       "name":  "W4"
                                   }
                               ]
               },
    "error":  null,
    "id":  "test"
}
```

I want to check if the JSON response above contains wallet name "W1". So I wrote this in PowerShell which doesn't work:

```cs
if ($w.wallets.name -contains "W1") {
    Write-Host "Wallet 'W1' exists"
}
```

How do I check something in above JSON using PowerShell?

Comment: JSON is a string representation. You'd need to convert it to a collection of objects to check properly, using `ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: From that JSON the condition would be `if($json.result.wallets.name -contains 'W1'){...}`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon It doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

JSON is a string. -contains won't work for it. You need to convert your JSON to an object.

In your example, you would just operate on `$wallets` and not even convert it to JSON, but let's assume your JSON actually comes from somewhere else.

```
$o = $w | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Now, you can operate on it like an object:

```
if ($o.result.wallets.name -contains "W1") {
    Write-Host "Wallet 'W1' exists"
}
```

Comment: `($o.wallets.name -contains "W1")` in `if` condition works from shell when `$o` is https://pastebin.com/raw/nibSGKpM But it doesn't work when I send a POST request to API with `ConvertFrom-Json` it returns error: `ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive:` and without it $o =$w is https://pastebin.com/raw/hMqNVXtv. Something wrong with API or I need to use something else when using POST request? Tried lot of things but nothing works

Comment: I have shared the script that worked for me in the answer

Comment: That looks like a completely different issue. At a glance, it looks like $w is your wallets array already, so you would just do `$w.name -contains "W1"`, but you'd have to post a full question with how you are setting `$w`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how did it get resolved but below script works:

```cs
if ($w.Contains("W1")) {
    Write-Host "Wallet 'W1' exists"
}
```

Comment: You changed from using `$w.wallets.name -contains "W1"` to `$w.Contains("W1")`.  `-contains` and `.Contains()` work differently.

Comment: This is not good... using the **string** method `.Contains()` on the whole JSON string may return $true also when some other element or even element Name happens to contain the (sub)string "W1". You really need to use the `-contains` or `-in` **operator** to check for that value in an array. As @GarrGodfrey commented, do `$wallets.result.wallets.name -contains 'W1'` or alternatively `'W1' in $wallets.result.wallets.name`. (if you need case sensitive matching, use `-ccontains` or `-cin`)